# How do I clean the bottom of a porcelain pan?

Tags: cleaning

How do I clean the brown (grease? burn?) stains from the bottom of a porcelain baking dish?

[image: dirty porcelain baking dish]

Soaking in soapy water doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Anyone know if a cycle in a self-cleaning oven would burn this off?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, mostly if it is unglazed/porous

(most) Porcelain dishes have porous bottoms, anything that touches it will be sucked in the small pores, and if baked in, will be more difficult to remove.

If the glazed part of the dish is clean, I would not think much about the bottom.

Some people will see it as a good sign that you are using it.

On the other hand, you could try using products like Bar Keepers and a plastic scouring pad to clean it.

Anecdotal, I keep the glazed part as clean as possible, and don't really care about the unglazed bottom.